# What is different between itms vs itms-apps when opening url from device

Tags: ios, itunes, applications, ios-appstore, url

I've an app in appstore and when it has an update the link was given in the format `itms://itunes.com/apps/[AppName]` Now I've recently uploaded a new version of my app and from the older app when I click the update link it takes us to store but doesnt give option to update. It gives a button saying open, I have to then take the store option again for download then it comes with the update option. So, I changed the link format to `itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/[AppName]/[AppId]` and this time when I clicked on the link it opened up correctly giving me option to update. Was this a new update in the format? What was the difference between opening link between these two formats?

Comment: Perhaps this link would be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433907/how-to-link-to-apps-on-the-app-store
To me it looks like there's no difference between itms and itms-apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `itms-apps:` will leads you to **App Store** directly.

Using `itms:` will leads you to App Store page in **iTunes Store**. You'll see "App Store" as navigation title and a button links you to App Store on the upper right corner.

I used to use `itms:` in my app. But I found that app status on iTunes Store was sometimes not up-to-date as App Store was. I haven't confirmed what caused this but now I use `items-apps:` instead.